# Is there any Powershell script to get/update term set navigation url

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint and need help in updating a url in sharepoint site. can some one suggest is updating that through powershell is better or any other suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
$siteURL="http://sp2013/sites/team"
$termStoreName="Managed Metadata Service"
$termGroupName="Global Navigation"
$termSetName="MyTermSet"
$oldUrl="/test"
$newUrl="/test1"

$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteURL
$taxSession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $site
$tStore = $taxSession.TermStores[$termStoreName]
$tGroup = $tStore.Groups| Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $termGroupName}
$tSet = $tGroup.TermSets| Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $termSetName}
foreach( $term in $tSet.Terms)
{
    $term.Name
    $NavURL = $term.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"]
    if($NavURL -match $oldUrl)
    {
        $NavURL = $NavURL -replace $oldUrl, $newUrl
        $term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl",$NavURL)
    }
    $term.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"]        
    foreach ( $subTerm in $term.Terms)
    {
        $subTerm.Name
        $NavURL = $subTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"]
        if($NavURL -match $oldUrl)
        {
            $NavURL = $NavURL -replace $oldUrl, $newUrl
            $subTerm.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl",$NavURL)
        }
        $subTerm.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"]

    }
}
$tStore.CommitAll()
```

Refer to: [SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata Navigation with Site collection relative URLs](http://amolmeshe.blogspot.com/2014/03/sharepoint-2013-managed-metadata.html)

Comment: Thanks Mate :) This helps

Comment: If the reply helps you, you can mark the reply as answer, thanks.